# Creating UITableView cell background like iPhone settings app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm using monotouch for developing iPhone App. How can I create cells in my UITableView in a way that look like this image:

[image]

Are their background just Images that are set as their background image? Or there is another way to get cells to look like this?

Comment: you dont waste time reading programming guides, do you?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html

Comment: I don't know the reason of negetive rates. However Thanks for all answers

Comment: vikingosegudo, you are right, but i have searches for this and do not find usefull things. I'm sorry for my bad research and thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using C#/MonoTouch, then you can do this easily with MonoTouch.Dialog. Examples can be found here: http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/monotouch.dialog

Answer (score 1):

They are what's known as `Grouped cells`, shown in a grouped format in a UITableView.

The style of your UITableView can be changed in Interface builder simply by changing the 'style' option from `Plain` to `Grouped`.

Alternatively, you can create it in code like so:

```
UITableViewController *groupedTableView = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

An example of **Grouped cells** in a UITableView could be the following:

[image]

As opposed to a **Plain style**, which resembles the following:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The table view is having the style `UITableViewStyleGrouped`.

You can create a tableViewController via the following code:

```
UITableViewController *myTableViewcontroller = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```